Ошибка constant expression required при использовании switch case для кнопок в android studio
Имеется конструкция switch-case со множеством вариантов.
Подскажите, как можно пофиксить ошибку в R.id.imageButton и т.д.
public void playSound(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton:
            clockStream= soundPool.play(clock, 1, 1, 0, noLoop,speed);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonErr:
            errorStream=soundPool.play(error, 1, 1, 0, noLoop,speed);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonCry:
            failStream=soundPool.play(fail, 1, 1, 0, noLoop,speed);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonPunch:
            punchStream= soundPool.play(punch, 1, 1, 0, noLoop,speed);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonSparkl:
            sparklStream=soundPool.play(sparkl, 1, 1, 0, noLoop,speed);
            break;
        case R.id.imageButtonTutu:
            tutuStream=soundPool.play(tutu, 1, 1, 0, noLoop,speed);
            break;
    }


Возможный дубликат вопроса: Доступ к идентификаторам ресурсов в Switch

Если вы хотите сохранить старое поведение, можете добавить в файл gradle.properties следующую строку:
android.nonFinalResIds=false


лучше было не пересказывать ответ из вопроса-дубликата, а проголосовать за закрытие данного вопроса как дубликата.
